# Change windows 7 culture does not reflec in the system date format?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, datetime

I'm having a problem with my OS, I put in to a culture that the date form is dd-mm-yyyy but when I retrieive the datetime in visual studio it keeps getting me the english date format mm-dd-yyyy. The worse in my case, is that when I run my program in different machines, some get me the right date format, and some give me the wrong date format.

What I can do to explicitly specify the date format on my OS(Otherwise the default option on the regional settings)

Comment: How do you "retrieve" dattimes in visual studio? I suppose you mean in a program you have written.

Comment: You have a point, exacty

Answer (score 0):

I would double check all of your configuration settings on your machine as application's should automatically detect culture settings and adjust.  Additionally, you probably don't want to be writing code to explicitly change your users' OS culture settings.  But if you want to override the OS culture and always display a particular culture's format, you use something like:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-GB"); //Great Britain
string formattedDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(ci);
Console.WriteLine(formattedDateTime);
```